# OOD - Setting value once so that it cannot be changed

Tags: java, oop, information-hiding

I am trying to understand the principle of information hiding. Suppose that I have a vehicle class with methods such as getSpeed, setSpeed, getEngine, setEngine, getVIN, setVIN, etc. To enforce info hiding, I wouldn't want to give client classes the ability to setVIN since a vehicle only has one VIN (I might be wrong). I am kind of confused on how to make this class apply info hiding. I wouldn't want to make setVIN to private. But how do you set the VIN once and not allow it to be set again afterwards? Or should I even do it that way?

Comment: Personally, I would use final fields set using a constructor.  This way every field has to be set, once and only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information hiding means you're not exposing the internal VIN field for direct modification from the outside. Having a setter does not violate the hiding principle, because you have the control over the fields modification.

In your case, if you want to make sure the VIN is only set once, best way to do it is by setting it in the constructor, and removing the setVIN.

BTW, although this is a general question (which is fine), if you have a specific language in mind, it might be worth mentioning. Some languages do not allow non-default constructors, for instance. In that kind of language, I'd leave the setVIN, but have it check whether the VIN has already been set when called. If it had, either ignore the call, or throw an exception.

Comment: Can you explain more about the control? Say in a scenario I set the VIN to 123, then a client code setVIN(321). isn't this violation of info hiding? I'm working on java btw

Comment: It's not, because you control whether the actual VIN member would be changed or not. For instance, you can check whether the VIN member is not 0, and if so throw an exception instead of changing the member. Or, you can remove the setVIN and set it in the constructor. Either way, hiding is in place since no client can set `v.VIN = 77` (assuming `VIN` is not public). As a side note, you might wanna add the `Java` tag to your question. Would get you way more traffic, and possibly more answers.

Comment: I see. Because in my lecture notes there was a sample Vehicle class with  get/setVIN and it said it was bad design because in reality, you can access the VIN but you cannot change it, so there's no point in having it. It also modified the code so that get/setSpeed were private

Comment: What is violating information hiding and what is not perhaps always clear cut. If you have a rather typical POJO with get/set methods which does nothing but get/set a private variable, there is really not much difference in practice - you might as well make the field public. (Not saying you should.) The idea is that by having the get/set methods, you can implement the storage of the VIN information in a number of different ways, say in a Map, in a database, just ignore the changes, and so on.

Comment: A classic example is if you have `getBirthdate()` and `getAge()` you don't know if the class stores these individually, or calculates one from the other. That is the information you are hiding.

Comment: @Dan, this all boils down to the actual problem you're trying to solve. In your case, a trivial setVIN makes little sense. As for the speed, having private getters and setters is not necessary because your own code can just as well access the variable itself, but it would sometimes be a good practice. Bottom line, the idea is to decouple the raw data-structure from the users of the data (which might sometimes be the class methods). This way, changing the data-structure implementation won't affect any of the data users.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a class / object has a property, conceptually speaking, it doesn't mean it should be public. A "property" can be assigned & changed with "getter" & "setter" functions, but you may only expose as public the ones you need.

You may say, "Show me the code":

```
public class JavaClass {

    // hidden field "name"
    protected String name;  

    // start property "Name"
    // note: uses "name" field to store the property
    public void setName(String value) {
        //set passed parameter as name
        name = value;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // finish property "Name"

    // start property "Id"
    // note: uses "name" field to store the property
    public void setId(String value) {
        //set passed parameter as name
        name = value;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return name;
    }
    // finish property "Id" 

    // hidden field "years"
    protected int years
    // functions works as "read-only" properties
    public int Years() {
      return years;
    }   

    // start constructor
    public JavaClass() {
            name  = "unknown";
            years = 1;
    }
    // finish constructor

    public static void main(String args[]) {     
        JavaClass javaObject = new JavaClass();

        //set name member of this object
        javaObject.setName("Visitor");

        // print the name
        System.out.println("Hello: " + javaClassExample.getName());  

        //set name member of this object
        javaObject.setId("Employee");

        // print the name, not the Id, but are the same
        System.out.println("Hello: " + javaClassExample.getName());  

        // and current years of age
        System.out.println("Years: " + javaClassExample.Years());       
    } // public static void

} // class JavaClass
```

Its not tested, but, I think, it explains my point.